# how to check if an html element intersects the bottom of the browser?

Tags: javascript, css

In this example obviously my div intersects the bottom of the page, how can I know from javascript if this element is intersecting it or not?

if for example: `bottom:0px;` not should be intersected

```css
.fixed{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:-10px;
  left:0px;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:blue;
  border:3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) function. It provides information about the size of an element and its position relative to the [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Viewport).

Then by comapring it to `window.innerHeight` you can tell if it intersects the screen or not.

```js
var elmBottom = document.querySelector(".fixed").getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

if(elmBottom > window.innerHeight) console.log("elm intersects the bottom");
else console.log("elm still fully in view");
```

```css
.fixed{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:-10px;
  left:0px;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:blue;
  border:3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I took reference from this [tutorial](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/dom/css/check-if-an-element-is-visible-in-the-viewport/#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20getBoundingClientRect()%20method%20to%20get%20the%20size%20of,in%20the%20viewport%20or%20not.), where the code checks to see if the element is in the viewport.

The code works by checking the element's position using `getBoundingClientRect()` against the viewport's height using `documentElement.clientHeight`.

In your case, since you only want to check if the bottom border overlaps, I modified the code such that only `domRect.bottom` is checked.

Finally, this method will show `bottom:0px;` as intersecting, and `bottom: 1px;` as non-intersecting. If you want `bottom:0px;` to intersect, add 1 to `documentElement.clientHeight`

```js
function isIntersectingBottom(ele) {
    const domRect = ele.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(domRect.bottom);
    console.log(document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    return (
      domRect.bottom >= document.documentElement.clientHeight + 1
    );
  }
  
  const ele = document.querySelector('.fixed');
  console.log(isIntersectingBottom(ele));
```

```css
.fixed{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:-10px;
  left:0px;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:blue;
  border:3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed"></div>
```